# keyup function validation is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried every possibilities but not getting the correct result. 
it works fine for two digit value, but it should work for any given value.
here is my code please check it and suggest me.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   
   $("#height").keyup(function(){
      var weight=$('#weight').val();
      var height=$('#height').val();

      if(weight>height){
       alert("Height should be greater than Weight");
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <label>WEIGHT(kg)</label><input type="text" id="weight"       
      name="weight" placeholder="weight"><br/><br/>
 <label>HEIGHT(cm)</label><input type="text" id="height"   
      name="height" placeholder="height">

</body>
</html>
```

i need to display an alert when the weight is greater than height.

Comment: Validation not working fir what values?

Comment: when weight is two digit value and height is a three digit value.. like weight=45  height=100

Comment: try using `parseInt` to convert values to integers before comparing them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are comparing the text values instead of the integer values.

Convert them to integers before comparing and it should work.

```
var weight=parseInt($('#weight').val());
var height=parseInt($('#height').val());
```

String comparison works differently than integer comparison, for example in JavaScript

```
"200" > "1999" // true
200 > 1999 // false
```

Answer (score 1):

***This will work for you.***

I have used [**`.blur`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_blur.asp) function to achieve this result.Not used `.keyup` or `.keydown` function because it will effect on every key stock of the user, `blur` will only trigger on the focus out from the input.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#height").blur(function() {
    var weight = $('#weight').val();
    var height = $(this).val();

    if (weight > height) {
      alert("Height should be greater than Weight");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <label>WEIGHT(kg)</label><input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" placeholder="weight"><br/><br/>
  <label>HEIGHT(cm)</label><input type="text" id="height" name="height" placeholder="height">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @NagarajPujar which part.?, **fiddle** is working well.

Comment: if you want that just change the `.blur` to `.keydown` but I don't think it would be a good idea, rest is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#height").blur(function() {
    compareHtWt();
  });
  $("#weight").blur(function() {
    compareHtWt();
  });
  function compareHtWt(){
    var weight = $('#weight').val();
    var height = $('#height').val();
    if (weight.length>0 && height.length>0 && weight > height) {
      alert("Height should be greater than Weight");
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <label>WEIGHT(kg)</label>
  <input type="number" id="weight" name="weight" placeholder="weight"><br/><br/>
  <label>HEIGHT(cm)</label>
  <input type="number" id="height" name="height" placeholder="height">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @NagarajPujar , your requirement is weight > height or height > weight? Your comments are bit confusing. Please make it clear.

Comment: height>weight  this is what i want.  @Aditya Rao

Comment: You mean your alert should be triggered when weight is greater than height. Right?

Comment: There is also a possibility that your input can be a alpha or special character in which case your comparison doesn't work. so make input type as number

Comment: yes. that i will make. but first it should work well for the given numbers.

Comment: If you use key up event you will end with wrong comparison as key up measures value before key press. Use blur event if you want correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#weight, #height').on('keyup', function(){
    var weight = $('#weight');
    var height = $('#height');
    
    if(weight.val().length > 0 && height.val().length > 0){
      if(weight.val() > height.val()){
        alert("Height should be greater than Weight");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
  <label>WEIGHT(kg)</label><input type="text" id="weight"       
      name="weight" placeholder="weight"><br/><br/>
 <label>HEIGHT(cm)</label><input type="text" id="height"   
      name="height" placeholder="height">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is working. If you try to enter weight that is greater than the height. alert will out. What do you mean not working?

Comment: weight=30  height=200 enter these values and check it friend.

Comment: What!?  Is 30 greater than 200?!  It is not man. You said, the alert out if the weight is greater than height.

Comment: yes man, i said  the alert should out if the weight is greater than height but in your answer if height is greater then also the alert is showing. it shouldn't alert when the height is greater. enter the values i have specified and check it once..